# Clustering 1000 images to find group of images with greater similarity

Tags: image, image-processing, cluster-analysis

I have 1000 of 2D gray-scale images and would like to cluster them in python in a way that images with more similarities stay in same group. The images represents simple geometrical shapes including circles, triangle etc.

If I wan to flatten each image to have a vector and then run the clustering algorithm, it would be very complicated. The images are 400*500, so my clustering training data would be 1000*200000 which means 200000 features!

Just wondering if anyone has come across this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a similar question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088372/how-to-match-texture-similarity-in-images/6088838#6088838)

Read my answer
Of course you don't use each picture as a feature.
In your case I would recommend features like:

1. Find corners and calculate their number
2. Assuming each edge is a straight line - do a histogram of orientations. In each pixel calculate the derivative angle atan(dy,dx), take the strongest 1% of derivative pixels and do a histogram. The amount of peaks in the histogram will correspond to amount of edges (will cluster triangles, squares, circles, etc)
3. Use connected components analysis to calculate how many shapes you have in the image. Calculate the amount of holes in each shape. Calculate the ratio between the circumference and the area o the shape. For geometrical shapes, geometrical features work extremely well

As you asked in the comment I am adding more info for issue 2.
Please read more about HOG feature [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients). I assume your are familiar with that is an edge in the image and what a gradient is. Imagine you have a triangle in the image. Only Pixels that lie on the edges of the shape will have a high gradient. Moreover you expect that all the gradients devide into 3 different directions, one for each edge. You don't know in which direction since you don't know the orientation of the triangle but you know that there should be 3 directions. With a square there would be 2 directions and with circle there will not be a clear direction. You want to count the amount of directions. Use the following steps. First find the pixels which have a high gradient value. Say from the entire image there is only 1000 such pixels (they lie on the edges of the shape). For each pixel calculate the angle of the gradient. So you have 1000 pixels, each may have an angle of [0..179] (Angle of 180 is equal to 0). There are 180 different angles. Lets assume that in order to reduce noise you don't need the exact angle but +- 1 degrees. So each angle is divided by 2 and rounded to the nearest integer. So totally you have 1000 pixels, each having only 90 options for different angle. Now make a histogram of angles. If the shape was a circle you expect that roughly ~11 (=1000/90) pixels will fall into each bin of the histogram. If it was a square you expect the histogram to be largely empty except for 2 bins with a very high amount of pixels in it and the bins being at distance of 45 from each other. Example: bin 13 has 400 pixels in it, bi 58 has
400 pixels in it and the rest 200 are noise split somehow in the other bins. Now you know that you are facing a square and you also know its rotation in the image.
If it was a triangle you expect 3 large bins in the histogram.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you elaborate on Section 2? It is not very clear.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate your time.